# Adding JAR to Login Items with AppleScript

Tags: java, macos, applescript

I am building a screenshot program in Java, and, I would like to give users the option to "add to login items" so far, here is the code I have tried:

```
String jarPath = Core.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to make login item at end with properties {path:\""+jarPath+"\", hidden:false}'");
```

I know the command is right, because when printed out it will show this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make login item at end with properties {path:"/Users/Debuginator/Desktop/Client.jar", hidden:false}'
```

The strange part is, if I manually enter this command into terminal, it works perfectly. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Try using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime`.  It is probably not parsing the arguments correctly.  Also, read the error stream output to get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Instead of using System Events, could you incorporate this method: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111226075701552 but also see: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83014/the-command-to-enter-login-items-is-not-working-in-10-8 in which user seems to answer own post about this hint being outdated (or incomplete)